# remove duplicate entries in one column and linearize the values in multiple rows to a single row

Tags: linux, perl, r

I have a table that looks like this:

```
DAPPUDRAFT_194440   Phosphorous     
DAPPUDRAFT_194440   Temperature     
DAPPUDRAFT_194472   Phosphorous Fishkairomones  
DAPPUDRAFT_194472   Temperature     
DAPPUDRAFT_194512   Fishkairomones      
DAPPUDRAFT_194512   Cadmium Zinc    Quantumdots
DAPPUDRAFT_195644   Salinity        
DAPPUDRAFT_195644   Phosphorous     
DAPPUDRAFT_196131   Salinity        
DAPPUDRAFT_196131   Phosphorous     
DAPPUDRAFT_196131   hypoxia     
DAPPUDRAFT_196694   Salinity
```

As you can see, it can have data in variable number of columns (separated by a tab).

The duplicate entries in the first column starting "DAPPUDRAFT_" should be removed and all the other values that occur in multiple rows should occur in a single row.

For Example in my input table, "DAPPUDRAFT_194440" occurs 2 times in the table and it has two values "temperature" in one row, "phosphorus" in second row as seen in the subset of data here :

```
 DAPPUDRAFT_194440   Phosphorous     
 DAPPUDRAFT_194440   Temperature
```

What I would like to see is: "DAPPUDRAFT_" should occur only once, and the two entries "temperature" and "phosphorus" should occur in the same row separated by a tab as seen here:

```
 DAPPUDRAFT_194440   Phosphorous   Temperature
```

Expected output:

```
DAPPUDRAFT_194440   Phosphorous Temperature     
DAPPUDRAFT_194472   Phosphorous Fishkairomones  Temperature 
DAPPUDRAFT_194512   Fishkairomones  Cadmium Zinc    Quantumdots
DAPPUDRAFT_195644   Salinity    Phosphorous     
DAPPUDRAFT_196694   Salinity            
DAPPUDRAFT_196131   Salinity    Phosphorous hypoxia
```

I tried with the "reshape2" package in R with the dcast function. But it does something totally different than what i wanted. Is there a way on the command line or R or perl that can help solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply with **awk**:

```
awk '{ r=$0; sub($1,"",r); a[$1]=(a[$1])? a[$1]"\t"r : r }
     END{ for(i in a) { gsub(/[[:space:]]{2,}/," ",a[i]); print i,a[i] } }' file
```

---

- `r=$0` - capturing copy of the record
- `sub($1,"",r)` - removing the 1st field the copy to store remaining fields in `r` variable
- `a[$1]=(a[$1])? a[$1]"\t"r : r` - accumulating values for same *group*(presented by the 1st field)
- `for(i in a)` - iterating through all grouped items
- `gsub(/[[:space:]]{2,}/," ",a[i])` - removing excessive whitespaces between words
- `print i,a[i]` - print the group name and its values

---

The output:

```
DAPPUDRAFT_194440  Phosphorous Temperature 
DAPPUDRAFT_196694  Salinity
DAPPUDRAFT_194512  Fishkairomones Cadmium Zinc Quantumdots
DAPPUDRAFT_194472  Phosphorous Fishkairomones Temperature 
DAPPUDRAFT_196131  Salinity Phosphorous hypoxia 
DAPPUDRAFT_195644  Salinity Phosphorous
```

Comment: That's awesome! Could you please explain the command?

Comment: @biobudhan, sure, see my explanation

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
$ perl -e 'while(<ARGV>){chomp;($x,$y)=split(/\s+/,$_,2);$hash{$x}.=$y;}for(keys %hash){print "$_ $hash{$_}\n";}' test1
DAPPUDRAFT_196694 Salinity
DAPPUDRAFT_194440 Phosphorous     Temperature
DAPPUDRAFT_195644 Salinity        Phosphorous
DAPPUDRAFT_194472 Phosphorous Fishkairomones  Temperature
DAPPUDRAFT_194512 Fishkairomones      Cadmium Zinc    Quantumdots
DAPPUDRAFT_196131 Salinity        Phosphorous     hypoxia
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care how lines and elements are ordered:

```
sed 'G;s/^\(.*\)\(\t.*\)\n\(.*\)\1/\3\1\2/;h;$!d;s/\n$//' file
```

For non-GNU `sed` replace the `\t` by a litaral TAB.